# Update a Microsoft Access Table from another table with distinct sub-query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I cannot figure out how to write a query to update a table from another table - using a sub-query (to get distinct results).

I'm essentially trying to do an update from the many side to the one side.

I've tried a number of different ideas including the one below, but cannot figure it out.

```
UPDATE MASTER_STANDARDS AS S

SET
S.LINE_SPEED_UPM = 


(SELECT DISTINCT 
STANDARDS_NAME,
LINE_SPEED_UPM
FROM
MASTER_DATA) AS D

WHERE 
D.STANDARDS_NAME = S.STANDARDS_NAME
```

Comment: Your SELECT DISTINCT subquery returns two fields which you're trying to put in the single LINE_SPEED_UPM field.

Comment: It's removed but the error is still the same: 

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(SELECT DISTINCT LINE_SPEED_UPM FROM MASTER_DATA) AS D'"

Then, when I click ok on the error message, it highlights the "AS" in "AS D"

Comment: Try `UPDATE Master_Standards LEFT JOIN Master_Data ON Master_Standards.Standards_Name = Master_Data.Standards_Name
    SET Master_Standards.Line_Speed_UPM = Master_Data.Line_Speed_UPM` (in Access you perform the JOIN before the SET).

Comment: That works (and typically this is how I do my updates from another table) but the problem is getting distinct values from the table I want to update from.  This returns about 4 times as many records (a sort of Cartesian product if you will)

Comment: Are all the Line_Speed_UPM values the same for all the Standards_Name values, e.g. if Standard_Name is A, are all the line speeds set at 20 for A in Master_Data?  I thought it would return too many records so I tested with Master_Data holding 6 records and Master_Standards holding 2 - LEFT, RIGHT or INNER join said it would update 6 records but only updated the 2 records in Master_Standards.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me Darren.  I ended up solving the problem by creating a temp table with distinct values, performing the update, then dropping the temp table.